# Compile Libtorrent Rasterbar with Android NDK anyone?

Tags: c++, android, sdk, compilation, bittorrent

Greetings, I am thinking of compiling Libtorrent Rasterbar that is written in C++ into Android using Android NDK so that I can build a torrent client for Android.

Has anyone did this before? If so did you find some errors and or issues during process?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Kaloksi

Comment: Did you try already? Or don't you know how to start?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me without problems when I developed a BitTorrent client for Android. Check Play Store (Android Market) for torrent clients, some mention in their description that they use native libraries as well.